# Compile SCSS to CSS in Nest.js

Tags: node.js, sass, nestjs, node-sass

How can I tell to Nest.JS to compile my SCSS files from assets into CSS format?

I have wrote this into `nest-cli.json`:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      {
        "include": "./assets/**.scss",
        "outDir": "./assets/",
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But SCSS files are being copied without a conversion and I have no idea how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Nest itself does not have the required tools, but you can compile SCSS to CSS with your script.

To do this you need to install `node-sass` and `concurrently` to run it with Nest together:

```
npm i --save-dev node-sass concurrently
```

Then go into `package.json` and modify `scripts` section: add tasks for SASS compilation and inject them into main build tasks:

```
scripts: {
    // ...

    // Add:
    "css-once": "node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass src/css/style.scss assets/style.css",
    "css-watch": "npm run css-once && node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass src/css/style.scss assets/style.css --watch",

    // Modify:
    "start": "npm run css-watch && nest start",
    "start:dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run css-watch\" \"nest start --watch\"",
    "start:debug": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run css-watch\" \"nest start --debug --watch\"",
    "start:prod": "npm run css-once && node dist/main",

}
```

Note, that there are two different tasks for initial CSS compilation and for watching changes because `node-sass` in watch mode won't compile SCSS initially.